# How to color a column's value based on a null value of other columns in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Column A in my report holds values say, 2, 3, 4, 5.  Columns B and C hold values that place limits on what Column A's values should be.  For example:

### Column A | Column B | Column C

```
2                 1                 3
3                                  
4                 1                 9
5                 8                 12
```

I would like the values 2 and 4 in Column A to be green because they fall within the limits, 5 to be red since it falls outside of the limits and 3 to be black since it has no limit restrictions.
How do you code this in the Expression Tab for Fonts in SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
=IIF(ColumnA < ColumnB Or ColumnA > ColumnC, "Red", IIF(ColumnB=Nothing , "Black","Green"))
```

Or

```
Switch(
ColumnB= Nothing, "Black",
ColumnA < ColumnB, "Red",
ColumnA > ColumnC, "Red",
True, "Green"
)
```

Comment: Where do you account for the red text?

Comment: sorry, "Red" instead of "Black"

Comment: Well how would you get 5 to be red?

Comment: I've updated it now, this should go in the expression for Colour property

Comment: because is < than 8 (ColumnB)

Comment: 2 and 4 should be green because they fall within the limits, 3 should be black because it has no limits and 5 should be red because it falls outside of the limits.  How would you handle the value of 3 and make it black?

Comment: Ok, you need three colours then you need another iif or a switch, I'll update the expression

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I needed!